# how to set up a symbolic link for README.md in a monorepo on github

Tags: github, symlink, monorepo, readme

given a structure like

```
/ my_mono_repo
.. readme.md
.. / packages
.. / .. / package_blue
.. / .. /.. readme.md
.. / .. / package_red
.. / .. /.. readme.md
```

I would like to have a single `readme.md` in the root
and just a link for the single packages
something like [this](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/packages/riverpod) (I cloned it to peak the solution, but with no success)

can someone enlight me?

Comment: Symbolic links are created with shell tools like `ln -s ../../README.md`

Comment: sure, but how does this apply on github?

Comment: You've posted the link to github where symbolic links are used https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/packages/riverpod You've answered that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sure, but how does this apply on github?

It does apply on GitHub in that the README will be stored, as seen in [`rrousselGit/river_pod/packages/riverpod/README.md`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/dd5d9b840ca270ea012da60c5e7c695ae552f333/packages/riverpod/README.md) as a symlink: with the relative path in it:

```
../../README.md
```

And it will have a special type in the index ([120000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8470315/6309), similar to [Linux file mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193468/7490))

Comment: yep... worked! thank m8 (stack is forcing me to wait to assign you the bounty, I will as soon as I'm allowed)